# Simple SVN post-commit hook for Jenkins on Windows Server 2008

Tags: jenkins

I have VisualSVN Server holding several repos with PHP applications on Windows Server 2008 machine.

I need to figure out how to deploy PHP scripts to production machines (2 Windows servers + 1 Linux/Apache), preferably NOT by setting local repos on them. I tried to use Jenkins but I'm having a hard time figuring out how SVN-Jenkins communication works.

I need a script that

- would be executed *every time* a commit is made and
- deploy *only modified* files to the production servers.

Can someone suggest a solution, please?

Comment: Do you have a problem 1) how to check-out a code from SVN to the machine were Jenkins is or rather 2) how to deploy artifacts to the remote machine?

Comment: SVN and Jenkins are on the same machine. Jenkins has it's own copy of data (workspace), and it's updated regularly about 10 sec after the commit. I need a way to deploy files from Jenkin's workspace to three different remote machines.

Comment: I have closed this as not constructive because there isn't a good choice for it. It is strongly discouraged to post identical questions on multiple sites, and I feel you're more likely to get an answer on ServerFault (or perhaps SuperUser - but don't make a new one there too!)